# Lebesgue measure and the curse of dimensionality (application)

Tags: limits, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, recreational-mathematics, applications

Apologies for the cryptic, *Harry Potter*-esque title; I really did not know how to name this! (Very much open to suggestions of more informative titles.)

Fix $\varepsilon>0$ and $a>0$.
For each $n\in\{2,3,...\}$, define
$$
S_n := \left\{(x_1,...,x_n)\in [0,a]^n : \frac{e^{x_i}}{\sum_{j=1}^n e^{x_j}}< \varepsilon \ \forall i\in\{1,...,n\}\right\}
$$
I'm having difficulty calculating the Lebesgue measure (denoted by $\lambda(\cdot)$) of $S_n$. Is this possible? If so, advice on how to do this would be very appreciated.

If not, would there be another way for me to analytically characterize $\text{limit}_{n\to\infty} \frac{\lambda(S_n)}{a^n}$? (I.e. how "large" $S_n$ is relative to $[0,a]^n$ as $n$ becomes large?.)

**Note:** Assume $\varepsilon$ is such that $S_n$ is non-empty for at least some $n\in\{2,3,...\}.$

Comment: Wouldn't any $\varepsilon > 0$ yield a non-empty $S_n$ for large enough $n$? We can always achieve a softmax of $1/n$ for all $i$ with points where all the $x_i$ are equal.

Comment: I suspect the restriction to the $a$-box makes this hard. If it were restricted to the unit ball, or the portion of the unit ball with all coordinates non-negative, it would probably be easier. Can we assume that $\varepsilon < 1/2$? That would make it somewhat easier, because we can only peg one $i$ at a time then, I think.

Comment: Oops, never mind what I said about the ball. I forgot softmax is translation-invariant along the diagonal, not scale-invariant.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\mathbb P=a^{-n} \lambda$ restricted to $Q=[0,a]^n$ be the uniform distribution on $Q$.  Write $\mu:=\frac1a\int_0^a e^x \,dx=\frac1a(e^a-1)$. By the weak law of large numbers,
$$\mathbb P(S_n^c) \le \mathbb P\bigl\{x\in Q :   \sum_{j=1}^n e^{x_j}  \le  e^a/\varepsilon    \bigr\} \le \mathbb P\bigl\{x\in Q :   \sum_{j=1}^n e^{x_j}  \le n\mu/2   \bigr\}  \to 0  \tag{*}$$
as $n \to \infty$. Standard concentration inequalities, e.g. Hoeffding's inequality, imply that the RHS of $(*)$ tends to zero exponentially fast as $n \to \infty$. In fact, by comparison to a sum of uniform variables, it can be shown that the middle term in $(*)$ tends to zero super-exponentially fast. See, e.g., [1] or [2].

[1] [Expected stopping time](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2404388/expected-stopping-time/2412737#2412737)

[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution